# XML to HTML ordered list

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to print out an ordered list from the following xml using the ssl rules... the html get generated for the list items but there is nothing printed in the list item itself. i am thinking that i am selecting each  item in  and printing out the value of step. what am i doing wrong?

XML:

```
<rental_listings>
<property>
    <address number="123" street="Main St." unit="1R" city="Townsville" state="broken" zip="10001"/>
    <description nbeds="2" nbaths="1" sqft="755" nparking_spots="1" pet="no" washer_drier="yes"/>
    <rent>825</rent>
    <application_process>
        <step>
            Get to the application page at: http://www.ineedaplacetorent.com.
        </step>
        <step>
            Fillout the form and submit with a credit card number
            to pay for the application process.
        </step>
        <step>
            Be sure and fill out the name of a reference whom you rented from before.
        </step>
    </application_process>
    <comments>
        This is a lovely apartment with mountain views.
        Cellphone reception is good as is TV reception.
    </comments>
</property>
</rental_listings>
```

XSL:

```
<div class="apply">
                    <H3>Application Process</H3>
                    <ol>
                        <xsl:for-each select="application_process/step">
                            <li><xsl:value-of select="step"/></li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ol>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are already in the `step` node. change:

```
 <li><xsl:value-of select="step"/></li>
```

to

```
 <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
```